# Regular express for first integer in between double quotes

Tags: regex

I have this input:

```
"1497660898","12104048"," ","","N","Y","N","Y","Y","776785344","","","-6156437426","-6156437426","1498885276","1499070495","791","791"
"1497660899","14099548"," ","","N","N","N","Y","N","776806021","","","-6156433269","-6156433269","1499021685","1498762671","791","791"
```

I tried this regular expression:
`/^"\d{10}/gm`

It returns "1497660898 which is the closest I could get to extract the first integer from both of the input lines.

I also tried `/(\d{10})/gm` which returns all the integers with size 10.

Comment: Which language are you using ? Your regex should work fine (maybe use a lookbehind if you don't want to match the quote)

Comment: I was verifying it on web
URL https://regex101.com/r/6jbCRc/1 
how shall i exclude the double quotes that are included

Comment: Just use a look behind : `(?<=^")\d{10}`. However lookbehinds are not accepted by all flavours. That's why I was asking about the language you use. See my edit : https://regex101.com/r/6jbCRc/2

Comment: I'm using Java in Pentaho ETL

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I didn't knew the concept of lookbehind

Comment: Ok I don't know about Pentaho ETL, but this should be fine for Java. Anytime ! ;)